# Palantir Foundry - run Spark-NLP library offline

Tags: palantir-foundry, johnsnowlabs-spark-nlp

I am trying to run the spark-nlp library offline in Palantir Foundry. We do not have egress configured to make http calls, so I'm attempting to use spark-nlp in offline mode by downloading explain_document_dl from the spark-nlp models hub. This is just a simple example I found in the spark-nlp quick start, I don't really have a goal with it other than to get it to work in Foundry.

Using [spark-nlp version 5.1.2 from PYPI](https://pypi.org/project/spark-nlp/5.1.2/), and I followed [these oddly specific instructions in the Palantir public docs to load the spark-nlp library](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/transforms-python/environment-troubleshooting/index.html#packages-which-require-both-a-conda-package-and-a-jar) so I know this has to be possible.

The method below of loading/extracting a zip file from the Foundry dataset filesystem worked to load BERTopic, so trying to apply it here. There are 6 different versions of [explain_document_dl](https://sparknlp.org/models?q=explain_document_dl&type=pipeline&edition=Spark%20NLP%205.1) on the models hub for spark-nlp 5.1, and it's not really clear to me how they are different other than the version numbers. I've tried loading all of them unsuccessfully. I also tried loading the pretrained model to see if I could tell which version it was reaching for through http, no luck.

```
pipeline = PretrainedPipeline('explain_document_dl', lang='en')
```

I'm not sure if this is a Foundry problem or an issue with how I'm trying to run spark-nlp offline, or both, so I'm including the spark-nlp tag.

```
from transforms.api import transform, Input, Output
from sparknlp.base import PipelineModel
# from sparknlp.annotator import *
from sparknlp.pretrained import PretrainedPipeline
# import sparknlp
from zipfile import ZipFile
import tempfile
import os
import shutil
import base64


def download_file(filesystem, input_file_path, local_file_path=None, base64_decode=False):
    """
    Download a file from a Foundry dataset to the local filesystem.
    If the input_file_path is None, a temporary file is created, which you must delete yourself after using it.
    :param filesystem: an instance of transform.api.FileSystem
    :param input_file_path: logical path on the Foundry dataset to download from
    :param local_file_path: path of the file to download to on the local file system (default=None)
    :base64_encode: if set to True, decode data using base64 (default=False)
    :return: str path of the downloaded file on the local file system
    """

    # Check if a different temp directory is specified in the Spark environment, and use it if so
    TEMPDIR_OVERRIDE = os.getenv('FOUNDRY_PYTHON_TEMPDIR')
    tempfile.tempdir = TEMPDIR_OVERRIDE if TEMPDIR_OVERRIDE is not None else tempfile.tempdir

    if local_file_path is None:
        _, local_file_path = tempfile.mkstemp()

    if base64_decode:
        _, download_file_path = tempfile.mkstemp()
    else:
        download_file_path = local_file_path

    try:
        with filesystem.open(input_file_path, 'rb') as f_in, open(download_file_path, 'wb') as f_out:
            shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)

        if base64_decode:
            with open(download_file_path, 'rb') as fin, open(local_file_path, 'wb') as fout:
                base64.decode(fin, fout)

        return local_file_path

    finally:
        if base64_decode:
            os.remove(download_file_path)


@transform(
    raw_model=Input("ri.foundry.main.dataset.6b9128f7-dc4b-4c99-81c8-94fb4b0f9ab4"),
    model_output=Output("ri.foundry.main.dataset.67b42a35-5105-41ef-83f4-b9ccfd347d93"),
)
def compute(raw_model, model_output):
    # Offline mode
    # https://github.com/JohnSnowLabs/spark-nlp#offline
    temp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
    model_package = download_file(
        raw_model.filesystem(),
        "explain_document_dl_en_4.4.2_3.2_1685186531034.zip",
        "{}/explain_document_dl_en_4.4.2_3.2_1685186531034.zip".format(temp_dir)
    )
    with ZipFile(model_package, "r") as zObject:
        # Extract all files from zip and put them in temp directory
        explain_document_dl = tempfile.mkdtemp()
        zObject.extractall(path=explain_document_dl)

        pipeline = PipelineModel.load(explain_document_dl)

    # Your testing dataset
    text = "The Mona Lisa is a 16th century oil painting created by Leonardo. It's held at the Louvre in Paris."

    # Annotate your testing dataset
    result = pipeline.annotate(text)

    # What's in the pipeline
    list(result.keys())

    # Check the results
    result['entities']
    model_output.write_dataframe(result)
    zObject.close()
```

Error building this transform - I see it's not finding a file it's expecting, but I don't understand what it's looking for since I'm just loading zip files from spark-nlp that I'm figuring have everything needed.

> {
> "errorCode": "CUSTOM_CLIENT",
> "errorName": "Spark:JobAborted",
> "errorInstanceId": "d0ec47f9-628c-411c-be10-ac3b1c81b941",
> "safeArgs": {
> "pythonVersion": "3.10.12",
> "exceptionClass": "java.io.FileNotFoundException",
> "message": "ServiceException: CUSTOM_CLIENT (Spark:JobAborted)"
> },
> "unsafeArgs": {
> "stacktrace": "org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 1.0 (TID 4) : java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/tmp/tmp67p250jr/metadata/part-00000 does not exist\n\tat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting this issue is that the `PipelineModel.load(...)` call requires that the full model folder structure be available on the driver and all executors - your logic is only unzipping and making the path available on the driver. You can fix this either by providing a path that is available on the driver and executors (in Foundry this is a shared HDFS path), or by just not using any executors.

**First option:**

The simpler approach is definitely to not use any executors and you can achieve this by adding the `@configure(profile=["KUBERNETES_NO_EXECUTORS"])`  profile to your transforms build. However, this method has the downside of not benefiting from spark distribution.

**Second option:**

If you need the spark distribution then you can use the hadoop path, but you'll need to upload the unzipped files to the Foundry raw dataset:

1. Unzip the files locally
2. Upload the directory as is into the foundry dataset (it is critical that you preserving the folder structure as this is required by Spark ML).
3. 

```
# KUBERNETES_NO_EXECUTORS not required for this option
@transform(
    raw_model=Input("<rid>"),
    model_output=Output("<rid>"),
)
def compute(raw_model, model_output):
    path = raw_model.filesystem().hadoop_path + '/<root_for_chosen_model>'
    pipeline = PipelineModel.load(path)

    # Your testing dataset
    text = "The Mona Lisa is a 16th century oil painting created by Leonardo. It's held at the Louvre in Paris."

    # Annotate your testing dataset
    result = pipeline.annotate(text)

    # What's in the pipeline
    list(result.keys())

    # Check the results
    result['entities']
    model_output.write_dataframe(result)
    zObject.close()
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thank you for saving the day again! One question on uploading files to a Foundry raw dataset - is it possible to create folders in dataset filesystems? I haven't found a way in the UI yet. Also tried extracting the contents of the zip file to the dataset file system. It looked like it worked in Preview but after I built there were no files in the dataset.

Comment: Happy to help!

When you upload the files into the dataset in Foundry, there is a confirmation "upload" dialog where you can adjust the names of the files. You can add the path in that dialog by changing the path from `example.txt` to `example_directory/example.txt`